# How to wait for promise before exporting a variable?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

How do I export a value only after the promise is completed? Suppose I have something like this in a `secrets.js` file:

```
var secretsData;

(async function () {
  secretsData = await getSecret(); // makes some async API call to AWS Secrets Manager
})();

module.exports = secretsData;
```

How can I wait for the promise to complete before exporting `secretsData`?

I want to avoid having to introduce async handling to all the other areas of my code that imports the `secrets.js` file (which could possibly bubble up to their parent functions and so on). In my opinion, it's just much simpler to deal with if I can just import and use the secrets with the assumption that it is already populated:

```
var secretsData = require("../secrets");
... do something with secretsData.url ...
... do something with secretsData.db.password ...
```

It feels like its a simple problem but I can't seem to find any solution to this. Most of the articles I've read seems to just suggest the only solution is to make everything that relies on the secrets to become async as well, but this feels like such a complicated solution for something so simple (especially when there are many places that depend on the secrets).

What is the simplest/idiomatic/cleanest way of implementing secrets (or some form of config) that depend on a promise to be completed?

Comment: You can use `await` at top-level in a module.

Comment: but only if you're in a recent enough version of the browser/Node, because older versions don't support top level await.

Comment: better export the async function and let the user await it.

Comment: I was about to write that too: instead of exporting "a variable", export the getting instead. E.g. `module.exports = getSecret;` (and then make the getter cache the result so that it only "really runs" once, and after that can just immediate return/resolve)

Comment: Your life will be hell if you try to circumvent promises and stash the result. Return the promise. If you blocked on something with await to avoid consumer using `.then`/await, I'd consider it deeply incompetent.

Comment: Sorry, once you go async everything that depends on that async result has to be async henceforth as well. Better to embrace async than to try to fight it. It's async for a reason. Export the promise and let the client await it wherever they need the result.

Answer (score -1):

Try

`module.exports = await secretsData;`

you can refer to here for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: This doesn't really help. You might as well do `module.exports = getSecret();` rather than adding 2 pointless promise wrappers on it. OP seems to be trying to make the export synchronous, but that's not really possible.